# Amino acid characteristics that determine their chemical properties?

Tags: biochemistry, homework

What chemical aspect of amino acids results in their having different properties such that the chemical and physical properties of polypeptides vary with both amino acid content and amino acid order?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question to me.

Comment: What differences do the amino acids have from one another?  There is your answer.

Comment: Look up amino acid R groups.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds seriously like your homework, so it'd be better if you researched. However as a starting point amino acids can be polar and non-polar. These properties cause varying forces of attraction between amino acids and their surrounding environment. The location changes the way they can interact. Ask if you are unsure about something :)